# Transfer dataframe from internal environment to other internal environment

Tags: r, dataframe, transfer

I am following a course in Datacamp and there's this dataset that I would love work with in my own R environment.

For transferring a dataframe from one R environment (environment X) to the other (environment Y), I know I could write the dataframe into csv file in environment X and then upload the csv file into environment Y.

However, since in Datacamp I work in a practice environment, there is no way for me to transfer the data within the practice environment (environment X) into a csv file.

My question is therefore: Is there an easy way to transform the data in a dataframe (environment X) to an R script that I can use to get my data into the environment that I want (environment Y)?

Suppose the dataframe looks like this in environment X: [dataframe](http://www.solver.com/sites/default/files/Utilitiesxlsx_0.jpg)

Then my ideal result woulde be a script like this:

```
utilities <- data.frame(utility_name = c("Arizona", "Boston", "Central"), 
                        utility = c(1, 2, 3),
                        x1 = c(1.06, 0.89, 1.43)) #etcetera
```

Comment: Use `dput(datacamp_dataset)` to get a copy/pasteable data structure you can then use in your local environment.

Comment: @akaDrHouse, thank you for your solution. This totally works! You were first with this solution, but it's a shame I can't indicate that you came up with the solution I'm going to use because you haven't used the Solution method of providing a solution. Maybe next time provide the suggestion as an Answer to the question in stead of providing a comment so that I can properly assign you some user points? :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `dput()` to output something you can copy paste into another R session

```
> dput(iris[1:5,])
structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4), 
    Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How I love R's simplicity! Thank you so much for your help!